¿Cómo obtener los valores que se encuentran en comillas simples en el campo siguiente que almacena un json en Odoo 16?
quiero armar una query en PostgreSQL para extraer datos que se encuentran entre comillas simples en un campo que almacena datos de tipo Jsonb. (Agrego una imagen para comprender lo que busco)

Los resultados que busco obtener solo son los valores que se encuentran en comillas simples. ejemplo el 357, 51....


Hola Alex, en teoría no el motor no deberías dejarte ingresar un JSON con comillas simples en claves cuando el tipo de la columna es JSONB. ¿Podrías compartir un [mcve]? Ejemplo
